# Embedding a control in a QTableView?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, tableview

I'm working a small qt app (using PyQt4) and I've come up with an idea but I'm unsure as to how to implement it. I have a QTableView that represents some data and I'd like to add another column to the QTableView that contains a checkbox control that could be wired up to some piece of the model. For example, something like this:

[image]

Note the Delete column has a checkbox widget for each row (although this is a web app, not a desktop Qt app, the principal is the same). Bonus points if I can select multiple rows, right click, and choose "Check/Uncheck Selected".

If any of this is unclear, drop a comment here and I'll clarify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implementing your own table model is more work than using `QStandardItemModel` (as @Andy recommends), but it does give you a fine control over what you want to do, so I'll try to give you a summary of what to do.  I assume you know all about [Qt's documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/index.html) and [PyQt's class documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html) and can look up whatever classes you need.  (I may be overexplaining if you already have a `QTableView` but better than leaving something out, I think.)

To get checkable states:

- Create a subclass of `QTableModel`.

  - Select some data structure to store the contents of your rows.  This can be pretty simple (a big internal list), or as complex as a SQL database (in which case see `QSqlTableModel` instead).
  - Override `rowCount`, `columnCount`, `data`, and `setData`.

    - `rowCount` and `columnCount` correspond fairly directly to what you use for a data model.  If you basically are using a 2D array (or list of lists), they can be as short as one-liners.
    - `data` is where things get interesting.  Item models store several different fields (which Qt calls *roles*) and what `data` returns depends on what role is being asked for.  Note that I talk about the data types of what's returned but it always needs to be wrapped into `QVariant`.

      - `Qt.DisplayRole` is whatever text is displayed in the cells of the table.  This is your actual data, and is by far the common case (so that this is the default role).
      - `Qt.CheckStateRole` is a boolean.  Returning `Qt.Checked` will display a checked check-box, and `Qt.Unchecked` will return an unchecked one.  If all you want a column to contain is check-boxes only handle this role.
      - The other roles are useful for icons, for background colors, and a number of other features but these.
      - Any unhandled role should return a `QVariant`.
    - `setData` is symmetric to `data`.  You should handle the roles you handle in `data`: `Qt.DisplayRole` for the actual data, and `Qt.CheckStateRole` for the checkboxes.

To allow multiple selection of rows and columns and cells.  To do that you want to understand [selection models](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#handling-selections-in-item-views).  The short version is:

- Set the *selection mode* on your table view: `view.setSelectionMode( QAbstractItemView.ContiguousSelection`).  This will let you highlight contiguous cells.  You can highlight arbitrary cells as well: see `QAbstractView.SelectionMode`.
- To determine which cells are actually selected following an action ask the table view for its *selection model* (note the **'l'**): `view.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()`.  You can iterate through these with a `for` loop.

To allow right-clicking:

- Override your view's `contextMenuEvent`.
- Create a `QMenu` and connect it to whatever slots you need.

For a more in-depth understanding read the [Qt guide to Model/View](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html) if you haven't already.  And definitely look at the [Qt item view examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/examples-itemviews.html).  Many of the ones describe are implemented in PyQt in much less code (including the two @Jesse mentions), and the tree model examples carry over to tables but with much less work (you need to implement much less, as described above.)

Answer (score 4):

You could also have a look at the QStandardItemModel, which gives you an interface to interact with items through a "checkable" state !

You could also inherit from QAbstractItemModel and use the role Qt::CheckStateRole...

Answer (score 1):

In Qt/C++ you can create a delegate for custom items in a column. I would assume you can do something very similar in PyQt. See the following examples:

[Star Delegate Example](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/itemviews-stardelegate.html)
[Spin Box Delegate Example](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/itemviews-spinboxdelegate.html)